# Bake shape key positions to texture

Tags: python, texture-baking, displacement

I am trying to bake shape keys as XYZ = RGB to image-textures. The script below is my first approach of storing simple world positions in image textures. Since position values can be negative and positive I split the values into two images. One is referred as negative, the other as positive. You can see the positive result here.[image: positive map]

If I setup a displacement using one of the generated maps, it should theoretically displace all the points to the worlds origin.(assuming displacement is set to XYZ=RGB, UV, Midlevel = 0.0, Strength = -1.0) That's where I face the problem. Even though the image values are correct(I checked them on a sample basis), the mesh does not displace properly.

To run the script, open blender and create any object with non overlapping uvs. Switch to edit mode and run the script. You should be able to find the images in the image editor after the script has finished processing. Any help is appreciated.

```
#import modules
#mesh needs non overlapping uvs and needs to be in edit mode

import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
vertNum = 0

#function to get all associated uv coordinates to given vertex          
def all_uv_coordinates(uv_layer, v):
    uv_coordinates = []
    total = 0.0
    for loop in v.link_loops:
        uv_coordinates.append(loop[uv_layer].uv)
        total = total + 1.0

    if total != 0.0:
        return uv_coordinates
    else:
        return None

#get uv layer and create list to store index, position, list of uv coordinates
uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.active
displacement_data = []

#run through points in bmesh and store displacement data
for v in bm.verts:

    uv_coordinates = all_uv_coordinates(uv_layer,v)
    delta_positions = [v.index, v.co, uv_coordinates]
    displacement_data.append(delta_positions)
    vertNum = v.index

#print(displacement_data)

#set image size
size = 2048, 2048


# blank image for positive position data
image = bpy.data.images.new("positive", width=size[0], height=size[1])

pixels = [None] * size[0] * size[1]

#draw all pixels black
for x in range(size[0]):
    for y in range(size[1]):
        r = 0.0
        g = 0.0
        b = 0.0
        a = 1.0

        pixels[(y * size[0]) + x] = [r, g, b, a]

# set rgb to world position data and run through uv coordinates to set image colors
for i in range(0, vertNum):

    r = float(displacement_data[i][1][0])
    g = float(displacement_data[i][1][1])
    b = float(displacement_data[i][1][2])
    a = 1.0
    for datablock, val in enumerate(displacement_data[i][2]):    
        x = int(val[0] * size[0])
        y = int(val[1] * size[1])
        pixels[(y * size[0]) + x] = [r, g, b, a]


#flatten list
pixels = [chan for px in pixels for chan in px]

# assign pixels
image.pixels = pixels

# write image
image.filepath_raw = "/tmp/positive.png"
image.file_format = 'PNG'
image.save()

############# same procedure for negative values


image = bpy.data.images.new("negative", width=size[0], height=size[1])


pixels = [None] * size[0] * size[1]

for x in range(size[0]):
    for y in range(size[1]):
        r = 0.0
        g = 0.0
        b = 0.0
        a = 1.0

        pixels[(y * size[0]) + x] = [r, g, b, a]

for i in range(0, vertNum):

    r = float(displacement_data[i][1][0]) * (-1)
    g = float(displacement_data[i][1][1]) * (-1)
    b = float(displacement_data[i][1][2]) * (-1)
    a = 1.0

    for datablock, val in enumerate(displacement_data[i][2]):    
        x = int(val[0] * size[0])
        y = int(val[1] * size[1])
        pixels[(y * size[0]) + x] = [r, g, b, a]


#flatten list
pixels = [chan for px in pixels for chan in px]

# assign pixels
image.pixels = pixels

# write image
image.filepath_raw = "/tmp/negative.png"
image.file_format = 'PNG'
image.save()
```

Comment: Why do you want to bake this to an image? This is a classical case where a simple textfile would do a much better job.

Comment: because I would like to fire shape keys before an armature. The order of operation in Blender is armature->shape-key->final mesh. i would like to have shape-key->armature->final mesh. an image based displacement modifier would work. I didn't have any other ideas.

Comment: Well, you can simply read the textfile and perform the displacement with your own script by transforming the vertices in local space.

Comment: well i would like to drive the displacment based on certain bone rotations, which is why I want to have it fire before. Otherwise I could just apply the shape key in the first place.